# Flutter iOS App Rejected due to UIWebView are no longer accepted

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using latest Flutter version and latest plugins but still my app is rejecting due to

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale
    en-PK)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

pubspec.yaml file

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  flutter_rating_bar: ^3.2.0+1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.0+3
  flutter_html: ^2.1.0
  jiffy: ^4.1.0
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  geolocator: ^7.1.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.6
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  android_intent: ^2.0.2
  badges: ^1.1.6
  google_static_maps_controller: ^0.4.1
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.9
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  async: ^2.4.2
  multiselect_formfield: ^0.1.5
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  flutter_twitter_login: ^1.1.0
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  social_share: ^2.1.1
  screenshot: ^0.3.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.1.1
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.8



flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/launcher_icon.png"



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I searched it on xCode also, but it will not show any UIWebView.

[image]

[image]

Please help me in that, I'm facing this issue from couple of days.

Thank you please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is a lot of dependencies you're relying on and some of those dependencies certainly use UIWebView. Flutter uses WKWebView and has completely migrated its APIs (the once that were using UIWebView) to WKWebView for IOS.

So, you need to find out which dependency you have out of the many there is actually still using UIWebView and remove it or replace it.

**Edit:** possible way to find the dependency causing issue is opening xCode, select the search tab on the left panel, and search UIWebView. See what packages there match your dependencies listed here.

Comment: Please have a look, I updated my question, Attach screenshot of searching UIWebView, It will not show any.

Comment: try `grep -r "UIWebView" .` in the project directories.